# Using Bash to concatenate the first 10 bytes of many files

Tags: bash, for-loop, concatenation

I am trying to write a simple **Bash** loop to concatenate the first *10 bytes* of all the files in a directory.
So far, I have the code block:

```
for filename in /content/*.bin; 
do
  cat -- (`head --bytes 10 $filename`) > "file$i.combined"
done
```

However, the the syntax is clearly incorrect here. I know the inner command:

```
head --bytes 10 $filename
```

...returns what I need; the first 10 bytes of the passed filename. And when I use:

```
cat -- $filename > "file$i.combined"
```

...the code works, only it concats the entire file contents.

**How can I combine the two functions so that my loop concatenates the first 10 bytes of all the looped files?**

Answer (score 3):

The loop will do the concatenation for you (or rather, the output of the sequential executions of `head` are written in order to the standard output of the loop itself); you don't need to use `cat`.

```
for filename in /content/*.bin; do
    head --bytes 10 "$filename"
done > "file$i.combined"
```

Answer (score 2):

With `head` from GNU coreutils:

```
head -qc 10 /content/*.bin > combined
```

For the very unlikely case you run into problems with `ARG_MAX` (either because of *very* long filenames, or a *huge* number of files) you can use

```
find /content -maxdepth 1 -name '*.bin' -exec head -qc 10 {} + > combined
```

Comment: Hmm. Might want to use find or xargs in case there are more files than will fit on a command line.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good hint in general. For OP's use case I doubt there would be a problem. But just in case, I added a workaround using `find`.

Answer (score 1):

#### You should use [@chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74281686/14122), but to show how you *could* use `cat`...

Here we have a recursive function that rolls everything up into a single copy of `cat`.

```
catHeads() {
  local first="$1"; shift || return
  case $# in
    0) head --bytes 10 "$first" ;;
    1) cat <(head --bytes 10 "$first") <(head --bytes 10 "$1");;
    *) cat <(head --bytes 10 "$first") <(catHeads "$@");;
  esac
}

catHeads /content/*.bin >"file$i.combined"
```

**Don't ever actually do this. Use [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74281686/14122) (or [Socowi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74281856/14122)) instead.**